# Cleaning up disk space on Centos OS

Tags: web-services, centos, space

I'm having issues with inconsistently my site going down (giving a 500 error) and when running commands getting:

`-jailshell: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable`

I'm a noob on the server.

I ran `df -h` and I got back:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        39G   24G   14G  65% /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/mailman
/dev/root       152G  102G   49G  68% /var/spool
/dev/root        39G   24G   14G  65% /usr/sbin
/dev/root        15G  9.3G  4.3G  69% /etc/mail
/dev/root       9.5G  1.3G  7.8G  15% /var/tmp
/dev/root        15G  9.3G  4.3G  69% /lib64
/dev/root        15G  9.3G  4.3G  69% /sbin
/dev/root        15G  9.3G  4.3G  69% /opt
/dev/root        39G   24G   14G  65% /usr
/dev/root       152G  102G   49G  68% /var
/dev/root       9.5G  1.3G  7.8G  15% /tmp
/dev/root        32G  164K   32G   1% /dev
/dev/root        15G  9.3G  4.3G  69% /bin
/dev/root        15G  9.3G  4.3G  69% /lib
/dev/root       1.8T  1.2T  639G  65% /home4/sitedir
```

`sitedir` being where everything is hosted.

I feel that 1.2T of mem being used is a lot. But i'm unsure. Is there anyway I can look at what's causing this amount of memory in `/home4/sitedir` and possibly how I could clean it up?

Comment: Well, you have 1.8T allocated for that FS, it's used at 65% so I guess it is normal. Nevertheless I think your 500 error has nothing to do with this.

Comment: btw - why is the question title about disk space but the body of the question is about memory?  Are you asking about disk space or memory usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, try running the `top` command as `root` and press the `m` key to sort the processes by memory once `top` is running.  You should see the processes using the most memory since the `m` key sorts by memory usage.

[image]

As I mentioned in my comment above, the question asks about disk space but then refers to memory in the body.  You have a command to give you the disk space ( `df -h` ) so I am giving you a response for the (possible) memory side of the your question, if indeed that is what you are concerned about.